# Absolute UTC offset in Swift

Tags: swift, timezone, utc, timezone-offset

My task is to create a string containing UTC offset during DST and during summer time (example: `UTC+1UTC+2` or `UTC+1UTC+1` if there is no DST for a region). My function looks the following:

```swift
extension TimeZone {
    public func utcOffset(for date: Date = Date()) -> String {
        var currentTimeOffest = self.secondsFromGMT(for: date)
        if isDaylightSavingTime() {
            currentTimeOffest -= Int(daylightSavingTimeOffset(for: date))
        }
        let currentInHours = Int(currentTimeOffest / 3_600)
        let hoursSymbol: String = currentInHours > 0 ? "+" : ""

        let daylightOffset = TimeInterval(currentTimeOffest) + self.daylightSavingTimeOffset(for: date)
        let daylightInHours = Int(daylightOffset / 3_600)
        let daylightSymbol: String = daylightInHours > 0 ? "+" : ""

        return "UTC\(hoursSymbol)\(currentInHours)UTC\(daylightSymbol)\(daylightInHours)"
    }
}
```

It works well and I've written tests for it. All is good but after recent DST changes in multiple countries the tests started failing, even though I pass a specific date to calculate the offset for:

```swift
    func testUtcOffset() {
        let date: Date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 1_557_482_400) //May 10, 2019 10:00:00 AM

        let warsaw = TimeZone.init(identifier: "Europe/Warsaw")! //eastern hemisphere, with DST
        XCTAssertEqual(warsaw.utcOffset(for: date), "UTC+2UTC+3")

        let shanghai = TimeZone.init(identifier: "Asia/Shanghai")! //eastern hemisphere, without DST
        XCTAssertEqual(shanghai.utcOffset(for: date), "UTC+8UTC+8")

        let barbados = TimeZone.init(identifier: "America/Barbados")! //western hemisphere, without DST
        XCTAssertEqual(barbados.utcOffset(for: date), "UTC-4UTC-4")

        let bermuda = TimeZone.init(identifier: "Atlantic/Bermuda")! //western hemisphere, with DST
        XCTAssertEqual(bermuda.utcOffset(for: date), "UTC-4UTC-3")

        let gmt = TimeZone.init(identifier: "GMT")! //GMT, without DST
        XCTAssertEqual(gmt.utcOffset(for: date), "UTC0UTC0")

        let lisbon = TimeZone.init(identifier: "Europe/Lisbon")! //GMT, with DST
        XCTAssertEqual(lisbon.utcOffset(for: date), "UTC+1UTC+2")
    }
```

2 weeks ago, the `warsaw` and `lisbon` timezones started failing, today `bermuda`. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: it is worth mentioning that in Poland ("Europe/Warsaw") on 27th October Daylight Saving Time ended, so we are not using `CEST` time (UTC+2) but instead of it, we are using CET time (UTC+1). I think the problem can be in using `isDaylightSavingTime` which is correct for the current date and use it to calculate for specific date. Maybe try to use `func isDaylightSavingTime(for aDate: Date) -> Bool` instead ( https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimezone/1387201-isdaylightsavingtime )

Comment: I'm working with an external API for the project and the field is described as:
```The string representing the ntpdata UTC offset with/without DST, in format: UTC<+/-><offset regular>UTC<+/-><offset dst>. As an example: UTC+8UTC+7 ```

So that actually makes little sense as this value will change twice a year in regions with DST, depending when the string was created...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few things:

- In your tests, you have the offsets for Warsaw and Lisbon an hour off.  Warsaw is UTC+1 during standard time, and UTC+2 during daylight saving time.  Lisbon is UTC+0 during standard time, and UTC+1 during daylight time.
- From your comment, it seems you're looking for the standard offset and the daylight offset.  However, the standard offset isn't necessarily the same as the *current* offset.  The current offset might include daylight saving time, or not.
- According to [these docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nstimezone/1387242-secondsfromgmt), the `secondsFromGMT` function returns the difference *including* the daylight adjustment if one is in effect.  Thus you should not be adjusting for that yourself.
- It doesn't seem to make sense to be asking the `daylightSavingTimeOffset` function for the offset on a date when daylight saving time doesn't apply.  You might get better results just using `secondsFromGMT` for two different dates in the current year.  A common approach is to get the offsets for January 1st and July 1st.  Whichever is smaller is the standard time, the other is the daylight time.  Keep in mind they may be the same if DST is not used, and they will be inverted between northern and southern hemisphere time zones.

  - Even with the above approach, this sort of algorithm ignores a lot of the complexities of time zones.  Consider that some time zones have changed their *standard time* at different points in their history.  Such an algorithm might mistake that as a daylight saving time change.
- A point of concern: Once you have your string generated, such as `"UTC+1UTC+2"`, how will the external API you know from that alone which set of daylight saving time rules to apply?  Since [daylight saving time starts and stops at different dates and times in different parts of the world](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2019.html), it's likely that the wrong dates could be used when interpreting the offsets.

Comment: Yes, you are right as to the offset being wrong for Warsaw, I have adjusted my tests and expected results since I asked the question: https://gist.github.com/KacperCzapp/163d2e49b75b6715332db8982a0428d7

As to the last point, I know the API is s**t and it doesn't make any sense to send the timezone this way. Better would be to send the identifier like `America/Phoenix` or `Europe/London`. But that's unfortunately an API that's being used already in production and we probably can't change much in it.

Comment: The approach with acquiring the offset for January and July seems to be working: https://gist.github.com/KacperCzapp/e22e99506397c3406a96a0a4dd88e8ee

The correct values for tests were taken from https://www.timeanddate.com